# Stylelint: нow to sort properties before nested classes

Tags: stylelint

I can't find a rule that would automatically fix this:

```
.a {
  .b {
    width: 16px;
  }

  padding: 2px 0;
}
```

on this:

```
.a {
  padding: 2px 0;

  .b {
    width: 16px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`order` rule](https://github.com/hudochenkov/stylelint-order/blob/master/rules/order/README.md) of the [`stylelint-order` plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylelint-order) to order things inside of rule sets.

To ensure nested rules come before declarations you should add the following to your Stylelint configuration:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "stylelint-order",
  ],
  "rules": {
    "order/order": [
      ["custom-properties", "declarations", "rules", "at-rules"]
    ]
  }
}
```